# Spring Integration reply to Publisher

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, enterprise-integration, spring-integration-amqp

I have 2 flows implemented in Spring Integration using DSL:

- **REST -> AMQP -> Consumer -> Service**
- **AMQP -> Consumer -> Service**

The first flow is just a HTTP Message **Publisher** for clients who cannot publish directly to AMQP.
How can I let the **Publisher** know when the message processing failed in **Service**?

I was looking at **Publisher Confirms** and **Service Acks** pattern with **DirectChannel**, so that the **Publisher** can synchronously receive the error message, if I understand this correctly. However
this will block the **Publisher** until **Service** returns (or throws Exception).
What are the options in Spring Integration (since it is EIP based) to handle such situation where the **Publisher** should be informed of message processing failures without being blocked? This is also more of a design question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REST -> AMQPoutboundGateway -> AmqpInboundGateway -> Service`

By using gateways, the outbound gateway will block awaiting a 'success' reply from the service.

Add an error channel to the inbound gateway; if the service fails, the error flow will be invoked, and you can configure that flow to return the failure to the calling gateway.

You can use an async outbound gateway if you don't want to block, but then you'll need some other mechanism to return the result to the caller.

Comment: Any patterns for returning result to the caller using async outbound gateway?

Comment: Websocket or Spring WebFlux (if the client is using a reactive REST client such as Spring WebFlux).